# Change the location of the .ssh directory on macOS

Tags: macos, ssh, directory, environment-variables, home-directory

When generating ssh keys, a folder called `.ssh` is generated in my home directory.

Is there any way to move this folder to another location, such as `.secure/ssh`?
As an example, I can change the location of `zsh` history files by modifying the environmental variable `$HISTFILE`.

In terms of ssh, the only information I can find is that the directory is hard-coded to `$HOME` in which case there is nothing I can do. Is this indeed the case? If not, what is the proper environmental variable / method for macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location of various items is `~/.ssh`. There is no option to change that directory, though various options exist for individual assets found in this directory. For example, `-F` selects a configuration file other than `~/.ssh/config`, `-i` selects a different identity file other than `~/.ssh/id_rsa` et al., etc.

Comment: Will I have any issues if I bundle all of these flags together into an alias?

Comment: Probably not, though I would recommend a shell function instead of an alias.

Comment: You can also simply make `.ssh` a symlink to whatever other directory you want to use.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to make a symlink... I'l try to whip together a function of some kind then. Thanks for the answer